# Redux: How to track whether data is locally modified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I know this is a bit of an opinion question, and it's long, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good solution in Redux.

I'm building a level editor and I want to show the user whether or not the data has been modified since it was persisted to the server. First, consider the data:

```
chapters: [{
    id: 1,
    levelIds: [ 2 ]
}],
levels: [{
     id: 2,
     entityIds: [ 4, 5 ]
}],
entities: [{
     id: 4, position:...
}, {
     id: 5, position:...
}]
```

A chapter has multiple levels and a level has multiple entities. In the level editor, you edit full chapters as one item, so if any entity or level changes, the whole chapter is considered unsaved.

**I want to track if the user has made any changes to the data since it was last persisted to the server.** I want to show a `*` for example next to the chapter name if something has changed. Criteria:

- Track unsaved (not persisted to server) status
- Status must work with an undo/redo system
- If some "nested" data is changed (like an entity position), the top level chapter must know it is unsaved, not the entity itself

I've explored a few options and I'll try to illustrate why I'm not sure if any solution is better than the others.

### Option 1: Store an "unsaved" flag on each chapter

This solution involves storing an "unsaved" flag, possibly in a separate reducer, that's set to `true` on any modifications, and `false` when the chapter is saved to the server.

**Problems**

1. There are many actions I need to track, so this is a bit verbose. I also need to manually track which actions actually modify the chapter. It may look something like:

---

```
function isUnsavedReducer( state = {}, action ):Object {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case CHANGE_ENTITY_POSITION:
        case CHANGE_ENTITY_NAME
        ...etc
        case CHANGE_LEVEL_TITLE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [ action.chapterId ]: true
            };
        }
    }
}
```

2. Most of the actions don't know the `chapterId`. For example if I move an entity, the action looks like `{ entityId: 2, position: newPosition }`. If I went this route I think I'd have to add the `chapterId` to all actions, even though they don't modify the chapter?

### Option 2: Track the last chapter object saved

On the surface this looks simpler. Whenever the data is persisted, simply store the current in-memory chapter object:

```
function lastSavedReducer( state = {}, action ):Object {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case SAVE_CHAPTER: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [ action.chapterId ]: action.chapter
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the view to check if the current data is unsaved it's a strict equality check:

```
{ lastSaved[ currentChapterId ] === this.props.chater ? 'Saved' : 'Unsaved' }
```

**Problems:**

1. The same as problem #2 from above. When I modify an entity position with a redux action, I don't modify the top level chapter itself. I'd have to modify all of my reducers like chapterReducer to return a new object (even though nothing actually changed). I could also store the "last persisted entities" object, but since all entities are held in one store, I couldn't track which chapters were unsaved, just that something was unsaved.

---

Is there an obvious solution I'm missing? Should I modify how my data is stored or my reducer setup? The normalized data in my reducers, and the many possible actions that can set "unsaved", make me unsure of the best way forward. Have you implemented something similar and already know the pitfalls or best way forward?

Comment: It's a hard problem to try and follow, and a bit of a difficulty that arises out of the UI being a pure function of the state, as it is in Redux. As such, my instinct is to go with the latter; storing the state of the object as it has been saved to the server, and comparing on render.

Comment: I think either option is fine, though I think the second option solves the problem in a more narrow way, where as the first option can be used as a methodology for anything being changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have normalized your data, and this data act as the source of truth of your application.

Why do you want the edition events, that are not saved yet, to modify directly this normalized data?

- It makes it hard to revert to saved state without refetching saved state from the backend (it shouldn't be required)
- It is confusing because we don't know if the normalized data is saved or not (your current problem)

## Best solution: keep unsaved actions on a list, but don't run them before save

Instead of modifying directly the normalized data, you could accumulate the edition actions in a list of your store.

At render-time, you have the ability to project your Redux store state with this list, so your store state does not change, but you can still connect to components the current edition state. This technique is very similar to event-sourcing and snapshots.

Imagine your store state looks like that:

```
const storeState = {
    unsavedEditionActions: [a1,a2,a3],
    normalizedData: {
      chapters: [{
        id: 1,
        levelIds: [ 2 ]
      }],
      levels: [{
         id: 2,
         entityIds: [ 4, 5 ]
      }],
      entities: [{
         id: 4, position:...
      }, {
         id: 5, position:...
      }]
    }
}
```

If a component needs to get the edition state, and the original state, you can do the reducing directly into `mapStateToProps`:

```
let Component = ...

Component = connect(state => {

  return {
    normalizedData: state.normalizedData,
    normalizedDataEdited: state.unsavedEditionActions.reduce(myNormalizedDataReducer,state.normalizedData)
  }

})(Component)
```

Your component will now receive both the currently saved normalized data, and the currently draft edition data. From then you can do your magic and shallow-compare everything of the 2 DBs to know what have been edited.

On save, you empty the list and apply it to your normalized data.
On cancel, you just empty this list (no need to refetch because you kept state before edition intact).

I'd recommend using Reselect and ImmutableJS for better performances, but without it should also work fine.

Note that this technique of maintaining a list of events is also what many people are using for optimistic updates (ie: giving immediate feedback after action of the user, without waiting for server approval, but having the ability to revert to previous state if server does not approve the change). Some useful links:

- [Lee Byron's Render 2016 talk (24")](https://vimeo.com/166790294)
- [Redux-optimistic-ui](https://github.com/mattkrick/redux-optimistic-ui)

Note you are not forced to do the reducing of your action-list in `connect`, you can also hold in your store directly 2 entries: normalizedData / normalizedDataEdited.

---

## Other solution: build a graph to edit from normalized data, and compare initialGraph != editedGraph

Instead of modifing directly the normalized data on edition, you could build a temporary denormalized graph. Thus you could build a copy of this graph, edit the copy, and shallow-compare the copy to the original graph to see if it was modified.

```
function levelEditionReducer( state = {}, action ) {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case LEVEL_DATA_LOADED:
          const levelData = action.payload.levelData;
          return {
            initialGraph: levelData,
            editedGraph: levelData,
          }  
        case CHANGE_ENTITY_NAME
          const newEditedGraph = someFunctionToEditEntityName(state.editedGraph,action);
          return (newEditedGraph == state.editedGraph) ? state : { ...state, editedGraph: newEditionState }
        ......
    }
}
```

Then after edition, you can see that `state.initialGraph != state.editedGraph` and display a save button and a draft status.

Note this shallow compare only works if you deal very carefully with immutable data structures, and you make sure you don't update anything that does not have to be. If `someFunctionToEditEntityName` return the same state as the input, it is important the reducer returns the exact same state, because the action actually did not change anything!

Writing this kind of code is not simple with ES6 but if you use other libraries like Immutable or updeep or something similar, if you try to set to an object an attribute to a value it already has, it may short-circuit the operation and make sure to return you the original object.

Also note that you will detect your lack of care early, because the Save button would be displayed while it should not :) so you probably won't miss that.

Once the data is finally saved, you can merge the saved graph to your normalized data